# How to register dataframe to table in databricks which can be accesed from another notebook ,but in same cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

How to register dataframe to table in databricks which can be accesed from another notebook ,but in same cluster?**We had tried to register table in databricks using spark.sql but we were not able to access that table in another notebook **

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Spark 2.10 you have to use createGlobalTempView("myView") and then accessing it from another notebook with spark.sql("select * from global_temp.myView") - please note the use of the qualified name. 
Of course, you need to be in the same cluster.

The old approach, that consisted in defining a temporary table, does not work anymore because of [spark session isolation](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/cluster-images/2.1.0-db1.html#changes-and-improvements).

Notebook - **A**

```
inputdf.createGlobalTempView("myView")
```

Notebook - **B**

```
outputdf = spark.sql("select * from global_temp.myView")
```

Comment: Instead of creating view,Can we create table for same.Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Apart from writing the dataframe as table into hdfs I wouldn't know. Sorry.